# Format dataframe for Plotly graphs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, plotly-python

I got a dataframe that has some columns, i need to use that data to plot a plotly line chart graph.

| ORIGEN | TIMESTAMP DATE |
| --- | --- |
| ORANGE | 2023-02-03 00:00:00 |
| ORANGE | 2023-02-03 00:00:00 |
| ORANGE | 2023-02-10 00:00:00 |
| APPLE | 2023-02-24 00:00:00 |
| APPLE | 2023-04-18 00:00:00 |
| APPLE | 2023-04-18 00:00:00 |

I need to transform it to this form.

| ORIGEN | TIMESTAMP DATE | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ORANGE | 2023-02-03 00:00:00 | 2 |
| ORANGE | 2023-02-10 00:00:00 | 1 |
| APPLE | 2023-02-24 00:00:00 | 1 |
| APPLE | 2023-04-18 00:00:00 | 2 |

I tried using PD.MELT and groupby but it didn't work.
I'm trying to replicate something like this:

[image: Plotly Graph that I need to replicate with my data.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = {
    "ORIGEN": ["ORANGE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE", "APPLE", "APPLE", "APPLE"],
    "TIMESTAMP DATE": ["2023-02-03 00:00:00", "2023-02-03 00:00:00", "2023-02-10 00:00:00",
                       "2023-02-24 00:00:00", "2023-04-18 00:00:00", "2023-04-18 00:00:00"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["TIMESTAMP DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["TIMESTAMP DATE"])

# Transform the DataFrame
transformed_df = df.groupby(["ORIGEN", "TIMESTAMP DATE"]).size().reset_index(name="COUNT")

# Create a line chart using Plotly Express
fig = px.line(transformed_df, x="TIMESTAMP DATE", y="COUNT", color="ORIGEN")

# Show the plot
fig.show()
```